# geocoding google map doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with my script.
I have everything set correctly but the geocoding does not work, when I enter the name of a city in the form that I created then I click on "geocoder" it nothing happens.
This is my code :

**Variable :**

```
 var geocoder;
 var map;
 var markers = new Array();
 var i = 0;
```

**Geocoding Script :**

```
<!-- GEOCODER --> 
  function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            document.getElementById('lat').value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
            markers.push(marker);
            if(markers.length > 1)
                markers[(i-1)].setMap(null);
            i++;
  } else {
    alert("Le geocodage n\'a pu etre effectue pour la raison suivante: " + status);
  }
  <!-- GEOCODER -->
```

**Form:**

```
  <div>
Adresse : <input id="address" type="text" value="paris">   
&nbsp; <input type="button" value="Geocoder" onsubmit="codeAddress()">
</div>
```

Full code ( Only html) : http://jsfiddle.net/hCmQb/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work.  Geocoding more than about 10 locations on page load will run into quota and rate limits, will take a really long time and is discouraged, geocode the locations offline and use the resulting coordinates to display your markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the geocoder is not running is this:

```
    <input type="button" value="Geocoder" onsubmit="codeAddress()">
```

You don't want "onsubmit" you want "onclick":

```
    <input type="button" value="Geocoder" onclick="codeAddress()">
```

The other problem you have is that your "map" variable is local to your initialize function.  Change:

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                                  mapOptions);
```

to:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                                 mapOptions);
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_GeocoderQuestion.html)

Comment: It works! However do you know if it is possible to remove the geocoder marker ? when i remove var marker = new google.maps.Marker({    the map crash

Comment: Sure.  Don't create it or add it to the map. (remove the code that creates a marker inside the codeAddress function).

Comment: i have remove position: results[0].geometry.location and it work thanks for you help geocodezip

Comment: hey GeoCodeZip, thanks for your answer, my geocode was not working until I realize that my variable too, had local scope to my init function. thx